# HMVC Design Pattern in PHP

Tags: php, model-view-controller, oop, design-patterns, hmvc

There are hundreds of tutorials of how to create your own simple MVC

I can't find any tutorial how to implement HMVC with it but I do understand how does HMVC work, it is a bit like Ajax, you can request many controllers from a controller.

Could you come up with small pseudo design or oop design how does HMVC work? So I will get rough idea where to start!

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the HMVC pattern?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263416/what-is-the-hmvc-pattern)

Comment: And see also Wikipedia [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentation–abstraction–control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentation–abstraction–control) for an introduction on the original pattern. (However the web frameworks repurposed it might have less to do with it though.)

Comment: http://techportal.ibuildings.com/2010/02/22/scaling-web-applications-with-hmvc/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all. There are two kinds of HMVC.

1 [Kohana](http://kohanaframework.org/) style. Where you can access other controllers within you application

Possible implementation:

- All request data (URL, POST, GET ...) are stored in Request variable. In this case none of controllers can access POST, GET or other request variables directly. All data should be taken from Request variable.
- When controller1 executes method to access controller2, new (fake) Request instance is being created and transferred to controller2. Controller2 does not know that he is executed not via real request, but fake one and process data as usual.

2 Real HTTP request over the internet. In this case you can access other online services within your controller. Unfortunately I don't know real world examples.

Possible implementation: using CURL